# Fiona error on installation

Tags: installation, fiona, pycharm

Receiving the following error when installing Fiona.Does anyone can guide ?

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 1):

Try seeing [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat).

Someone was facing the same issue with different package.

Comment: donwload Fiona for Windows at [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)